# Translation for "hypocrite"

Tags: translation

What would the most apt translation for the word "hypocrite" be in German?

In the Duden the word [Hypokrit](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hypokrit) does exist, though I believe it is used very rarely.

Some other online dictionaries translate it as "Heuchler", though that doesn't really describe the pretense that lies in the meaning of hypocrite.

I have also read that "jemand der eine Doppelmoral hat" is an alternative way of describing a hypocrite.

Comment: Ich glaube, wir haben kein ebenso eingängiges Wort für jemanden, der Wasser predigt und Wein trinkt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree with Marcus Schaetzles comment. The most accurate and common used translations are in this order:

1. Heuchler/in {m/f}
2. Pharisäer {m}
3. Scheinheiliger/Scheinheilige {m/f}

Also these are notable in addition, but rather rarely used and heard:

1. Frömmler {m/f}
2. Duckmäuser {m}
3. Hypokrit {m}

Questions and answers, related to and based on 'Etymology' + 'Onomastic' should always refer to dictionaries queries, imo, therefore:

> **hypocrite**     [I. \ˈhipəˌkrit, usu -id.+V\ noun]

**Etymology:**

- Middle English `ipocrite`,
- from Old French `ypocrite`,
- from Late Latin `hypocrita`,
- from Greek `hypokritēs`, actor on the stage, pretender, hypocrite, from hypokrinesthai

> **Example:**

One who pretends to be what he is not or to have principles or beliefs that he does not have; especially: One who falsely assumes an appearance of virtue or religion:

```
I dare swear he is no hypocrite, but prays from his heart — Shakespeare
```

**Source:** Webster's Unabridged Dictionary